# Private instance variable "not initialized" in GUI (java)

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a class which extends JFrame and implements ActionListener.
I have a private int "currentSize". It is initialized in the constructor. There are methods which are called by actionPerformed which use "currentSize". When I try  to compile, it says "variable type might not have been initialized", highlighting uses of currentSize. I understand why this error occurs, but how do I fix it?

```
class GUIinterface extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ...
    private int currentSize;
    ...

    public GUIinterface()
    {
        super("Contact database");

        contact = new Contact[1000];
        currentSize = 0;
        currentState = STATE_NOTHING;

        setSize(600, 400);
        createMenu();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createParseEmail()
    {
        Component[] component = formCreate.getComponents();
        String value;

        long customerID;
        int type;
        String email;
        String user;
        String domain;

        // ID
        value = ((JTextField)(component[1])).getText();
        try
        {
            customerID = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            formCreate.remove(17);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" Customer ID is a long integer");
            formCreate.add(label, 17);
            return;
        }

        // type
        value = ((JTextField)(component[3])).getText();
        try
        {
            customerID = Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            formCreate.remove(17);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" Contact type is an integer");
            formCreate.add(label, 17);
            return;
        }

        // email
        email = ((JTextField)(component[5])).getText();
        if (email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.indexOf(".") == -1)
        {
            formCreate.remove(17);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" Valid email required");
            formCreate.add(label, 17);
            return;
        }
        user = email.split("@")[0];
        domain = email.split("@")[1];
        if (user.length() < 1 || domain.length() < 1)
        {
            formCreate.remove(17);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(" Valid email required");
            formCreate.add(label, 17);
            return;
        }

        contact[currentSize] = new EmailContact(customerID, user, domain, type);
        currentSize++; // causes error; am not allowed to use dynamic arrays
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JMenuItem)
        {
            if (command.equals("CREATE_CONTACT"))
            {
                currentState = STATE_CREATE;
                setupCreate();
            }
            if (command.equals("ERASE_CONTACT"))
            {
                currentState = STATE_ERASE;
            }
            if (command.equals("DISPLAY_CONTACTS"))
            {
                currentState = STATE_DISPLAY;
            }
            if (command.equals("FIND_CONTACT"))
            {
                currentState = STATE_FIND;
            }
        } // end of MenuItem

        if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
        {
            if (currentState == STATE_CREATE)
            {
                if (command.equals("CREATE_TELEPHONE"))
                {
                    setupCreateTelephone();
                }
                else if (command.equals("CREATE_EMAIL"))
                {
                    setupCreateEmail();
                }
                else if (command.equals("CREATE_POSTAL"))
                {
                    setupCreatePostal();
                }
                else if (command.equals("CREATE_TELEPHONE_REGISTER"))
                {
                    createParseTelephone();
                }
                else if (command.equals("CREATE_EMAIL_REGISTER"))
                {
                    createParseEmail();
                }
                else if (command.equals("CREATE_POSTAL_REGISTER"))
                {
                    createParsePostal();
                }
            }
        }
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

BTW I'm using DrJava with Java ver. 7_45
** Apologies if my previous code was too sparce

Comment: Please show the real code. Indicate which line causes the error. An instance field is always initialized at least to its default value which is 0 for an int, and your error suggests that a shadow variable inside of a method or constructor is causing the problem.

Comment: If it says `variable type might not have been initialized`, what does `currentSize` have to do with it?

Comment: Especially show the constructor code.  I'm willing to bet that first `...` includes an `if`, `while`, or `return`.

Comment: To follow on from @HovercraftFullOfEels' request, when asking a question about a compilation error, it is essential to show *real* code, not pseudocode that kind-of looks like the real code.  You should aim to construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The real code is immensely long.. but i'll try to cut only to what is necessary

Comment: Your edits are still not complete enough at least for me to understand the problem. If your class is truly "immensely long" then that in itself is a significant problem that should be fixed, a fix that will make both your and our debugging immensely easier. Refactor, refactor, refactor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `contact[currentSize] = new EmailContact(customerID, user, domain, type);` uses variable `type`, but no line before it ever gives the local variable `type` a value.

Comment: Wow.. that works.. Dr.Java was highlighting the wrong line... >.< WTF
Many thanks